# MongoDB aggregate $lookup to return unmatched items from the main collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like unmatched data from the `USERS` collection. Here I have two collections `1) USERS`, `2) COMPANY`.I am able to get the matched data from both `USERS` using aggregate function. but in this case I want data from USERS table which are not assigned to a company.

**USERS table**

```
{
 _id: "AAA",
 fullName:"John Papa"
},
{
_id: "BBB",
fullName:"Robin Son"
}
```

**COMPANY table**

```
{
 _id: "1sd1s",
 Name:"Lumbar Company"
 User:"AAA"
},
{
 _id: "23s1dfs3",
 Name:"Patricia"
 User:"AAA"
}
```

Comment: So the output should be `{
_id: "BBB",
fullName:"Robin Son"
}`?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet yes output should be `{ _id: "BBB", fullName:"Robin Son" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) works like LEFT OUTER JOIN so it will remove empty array when there's no match. Then you can use [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/index.html) to get only empty arrays:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "company",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "User",
            as: "companies"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [ { "$size": "$companies" }, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QV0aTn1dALN)

Comment: Thank you for solution :-) This was very helpful to me. I did small change at `$match` step, `$match: {       companies: { $exists: true, $eq: [] } }` [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RrLahqUqVzw)